# how to create multi recyclerview that displays data per category

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-context

In my project, I want to display information from firebase to recycleview per category query, for example:

layout 1 contains the menu query A
  layout 2 contains a menu query B
etc.

this is my code

```
   @ Override
     protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
         setContentView (R.layout.activity_post_list);



     // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar ();
       // actionBar.setTitle ("post list");

         mRecyclerView = findViewById (R.id.recyclerView);
         mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize (true);
         mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this));
         mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();

         mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference ("Data / Menu1"); //this section takes queries from firebase addresses


     }
```

[this is my firebase query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqDQQ.png)

how to make multi recycleview without making many classes ?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what are you trying to achieve? Your question seems unclear.

Comment: I want to display data from firebase to many recycler views, in my firebase query there are many categories where I want to display each sub query with a different layout.

Comment: As per your firebase screenshot, I can see that the pattern for all the items is same. Every data is inside a category, ex: Menu 1, Menu 2 etc. For such data pattern, you do not need multiple recycler views. This can easily be achieved using a single Layout also

Comment: So which part should I make / make? I'm very confused how to make a single layout that can make different queries. sorry I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this activity as a sample to get you started

**SampleActivity.java**

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference mRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    ArrayList<InnerDataModel> innerDataModelsMenu1ForAdapter;
    ArrayList<InnerDataModel> innerDataModelsMenu2ForAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        innerDataModelsMenu1ForAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
        innerDataModelsMenu2ForAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        getDataFromFirestore();
    }

    private void getDataFromFirestore() {

        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data/");
        //Get all the data from the Firbase Realtime Database
        mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String menuType = snapshot.getKey();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(menuType)) {
                        //Write logic for each different menu type

                        ArrayList<InnerDataModel> innerDataModelsMenu1 = new ArrayList<InnerDataModel>();
                        ArrayList<InnerDataModel> innerDataModelsMenu2 = new ArrayList<InnerDataModel>();

                        if (menuType.equals("Menu1")) {

                            for (DataSnapshot snapshotInner : dataSnapshot.child("Menu1").getChildren()) {
                                innerDataModelsMenu1.add(snapshotInner.getValue(InnerDataModel.class));
                            }

                            runCodeForMenu1(innerDataModelsMenu1);
                        }
                        if (menuType.equals("Menu2")) {

                            for (DataSnapshot snapshotInner : dataSnapshot.child("Menu2").getChildren()) {
                                innerDataModelsMenu2.add(snapshotInner.getValue(InnerDataModel.class));
                            }

                            runCodeForMenu2(innerDataModelsMenu2);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //No Data present
            }

        });


    }

    private void runCodeForMenu2(ArrayList<InnerDataModel> children) {

        innerDataModelsMenu2ForAdapter.addAll(children);
        Log.d("SampleActivity", innerDataModelsMenu2ForAdapter.toString() + "");

    }

    private void runCodeForMenu1(ArrayList<InnerDataModel> children) {
        innerDataModelsMenu1ForAdapter.addAll(children);
        Log.d("SampleActivity", innerDataModelsMenu1ForAdapter.toString() + "");
    }
}
```

**InnerDataModel.java**

```
public class InnerDataModel {
    private String image;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Once you receive and process the data from the FireBase, you can process your adapter based on the two global `ArrayLists` `innerDataModelsMenu1ForAdapter` and `innerDataModelsMenu2ForAdapter` and process it in your activity to show the data in `CardView`

Answer (score 0):

Android Development Tutorial - Recycler View in Recycler View like Google Play using Firebase Realtime Database.

I hope this video will help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2FSLZzYnnQ&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

To show data per category you can use sectional adapter. Please take a look for an example
https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter